# How to load multiple pages using retrofit and mvvm

Tags: java, android, mvvm, retrofit2, rx-java

I'm using Retrofit, RxJava and MVVM pattern in my app.

I have API that retrieve me a list of movies.

In the API request I must to say what page I want to load ( The API retrieve me 1 page (20 items) for each request).

At the start of the app I want to load 3 pages.

How to I do that?

That what i have now:

Repository:

```
public MutableLiveData<List<MoviesResult>> getMoviesResultsMutableLiveData(String sort_by, int page, String with_genres, String with_cast) {
        MoviesService moviesService = RetrofitInstance.getMoviesService();
        mDisposable = moviesService.getMovies(
                mApplication.getResources().getString(R.string.api_key),
                sort_by,
                UserSettings.getInstance().includeAdults(),
                true, page, with_genres, with_cast)
                .retryWhen(throwable ->
                        throwable.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<MoviesResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(MoviesResponse moviesResponse) throws Throwable {
                        mMoviesResultsMutableLiveData.setValue(moviesResponse.getMoviesResults());
                        mDisposable.dispose();
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
                        CustomToast customToast = new CustomToast(mApplication.getApplicationContext());
                        customToast.makeCustomText(throwable.getMessage());
                        mDisposable.dispose();
                    }
                });
        return mMoviesResultsMutableLiveData;
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public MutableLiveData<List<MoviesResult>> getMoviesResultMutableLiveData(String sort_by, int page, String with_genres, String with_cast) {
        return mMoviesRepository.getMoviesResultsMutableLiveData(sort_by, page, with_genres, with_cast);
    }
```

And MainActivity:

```
mMoviesViewModel.getMoviesResultMutableLiveData(getString(R.string.sort_by_popularity), 1, null, null)
                .observe(this, new Observer<List<MoviesResult>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(List<MoviesResult> moviesResults) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: "+moviesResults.size());
                    }
                });
```

I've tried to make a for loop in main activity when "i" equals to pages I want to load, and then set the i to the page in getMovies method - but it's not worked for me.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            mMoviesViewModel.getMoviesResultMutableLiveData(getString(R.string.sort_by_popularity), i, null, null)
                    .observe(this, new Observer<List<MoviesResult>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(List<MoviesResult> moviesResults) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: "+moviesResults.size());
                        }
                    });
        }
```

In this case i receive only 1 page .

Answer (score 0):

Link to add Paging without using paging library [Link](https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/pagination-in-recyclerview-without-paging-library-1c48e9328f81)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to add logic inside your View (Activity/Fragment), you are using a for loop inside View which is not ideal. So move this into your ViewModel or UseCase.

---

RxJava has an operator named [concatWith](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) which concats multiple observables together. thus when your Activity/Fragment lunches you can initiate three API calls and contact them together and return the three as a single model to your observer.

---

By the way, Using Android [Paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview) from Android Jetpack is a better solution for what you what to achieve.